# How to make a callback funciton to a drupal behaviors funtion

Tags: 7

I have this Drupal behaviors function:

```
(function ($) {




    Drupal.behaviors.modulenameSwiper = {
        attach : function (context, settings) {
        if ( location.pathname != '/en/imce' ||              location.pathname != '/fr/imce' ||              location.pathname != '/it/imce'     ) {

        var mySwiper = new Array();
        var mySwiperIndex = 0;

        $('.swiper-container').each(function (){
          mySwiper[mySwiperIndex] = new Swiper ($(this)[0],{
              mode:'horizontal',
              loop: false, 
              slidesPerView: 'auto'
              });
          });

          mySwiperIndex++;

    }
    }
  }
 }(jQuery));
```

I need to call mySwiper object out of the Behaviors callback. there is anyway to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign mySwiper to a property within the behavior.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.modulenameSwiper = {
    attach : function (context, settings) {
      if ( location.pathname != '/en/imce' || location.pathname != '/fr/imce' ||              location.pathname != '/it/imce'     ) {
        mySwiper = this.get();
        $('.swiper-container').each(function (){
          mySwiper.instances[mySwiper.index] = new Swiper ($(this)[0],{
            mode:'horizontal',
            loop: false, 
            slidesPerView: 'auto'
          });
        });
      }
    },
    /**
     * Returns an object with Swiper instances and highest index.
     */
    getSwipper : function () {
      if (this.mySwiper === 'undefined') {
        this.mySwiper.instances = new Array();
        this.mySwiper.index = 0;
      } else {
        this.mySwiper.index++;
      }
      return this.mySwiper;
    },
  };

  $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(Drupal.behaviors.modulenameSwiper.getSwiper());
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Hello Juampy, Thanks, but the problem is that I need to make a callback out of the Drupal.behaviors.modulenameSwiper . So If I try to call it, it doesn't work. It told my that it's not defined.

Comment: @OskarCalvo Surely you mean `Drupal.behaviors.modulenameSwiper.attach()`? By "make a callback" I'm assuming you mean "call/invoke the function"?

Comment: Hello Clive. Drupal.behaviors.modulenameSwiper.attach() give me access to the function. What I need is to load every mySwiper object and rebuild it.

Comment: Ah ok, this isn't really related to Drupal in any way - you're just trying to gain access to variables outside your current scope, purely a javascript thing. I would go with Juampy's solution, and use `Drupal.attachBehaviors()` afterwards

Comment: Juampy, yours code Works, I don't see the line "Drupal.behaviors.modulenameSwiper.mySwiper = mySwiper;", and it's the trick.
Thanks Juampy and Clive.